# Set NODE_ENV using variable

Tags: github-actions

I have a GitHub repo with structure as shown below:

```
├── packages
│   ├── packageA
│   │   ├── src
│   │   ├── .eslintrc.json
│   │   ├── jest.config.ts
│   │   ├── package.json
│   ├── packageB
│   │   ├── src
│   │   ├── .eslintrc.json
│   │   ├── jest.config.ts
│   │   ├── package.json
│   ├── packageC
│   │   ├── src
│   │   ├── .eslintrc.json
│   │   ├── jest.config.ts
│   │   ├── package.json
├── .gitignore
└── README.md
```

I have a GitHub Actions workflow like below that will trigger when a PR is created:

```yaml
name: Pre checks (eslint, test coverage)
on:
  push:
    branches: #all branches except master
      - '**' # matches every branch
      - '!master' # excludes master
jobs:
  test:
    name: Lint the source code
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
    steps:
      - name: Get branch name
        run: echo "branch=${{GITHUB_BASE_REF}##*/}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
        id: get_branch_name
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT || github.token }}
      - name: Setup node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
        working-directory: ./packages/${{ steps.get_branch_name.outputs.branch }}/
      - name: Lint
        run: npm run lint
        working-directory: ./packages/${{ steps.get_branch_name.outputs.branch }}/
      - name: Test
        run: npm test
        working-directory: ./packages/${{ steps.get_branch_name.outputs.branch }}/
```

`test` script is already there to run `npm test`.

However, in my `jest.config.ts` files, I have set the `coverageThreshold` like below.

```js
  coverageThreshold: {
    dev: {
      branches: 50, 
      functions: 50,
      lines: 50,
      statements: 50,
    },
    'qa-non-prod': {
      branches: 75,
      functions: 75,
      lines: 75,
      statements: 75,
    },
    prod: {
      branches: 95,
      functions: 95,
      lines: 95,
      statements: 95,
    },
  },
```

On my local, I do `"test": "SET NODE_ENV=dev jest"` to take the `coverageThreshold` specified for `dev`. Now, how can I do that in GitHub Actions?  I want to do that using "variables" in GitHub so that I can change that easily (if I do that in code, I will have to make changes to code and commit time and again).

Comment: If your script is `"test": "SET NODE_ENV=dev jest"` then this _already_ happens in the workflow. If not, set an `env`ironment variable the same way you would for any step.